# How to get certificates list in SIM7000E (SIM7000)?

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, mqtt, at-command, raspberry-pi4

SimCom SIM7600 Series use AT+CCERTDELE to delete certificates. Also here is AT+CCERTLIST command to get list certificates. Can we check the same in SIM7000?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to verify the modem or you're hosting a domain with the IP of your modem, then you should upload your certificate and list of trusted CA's to the device in the `customer` folder. You can then set them with the `AT+SHSSL` command.

If you're just trying to make HTTPS requests you don't need to do anything with certificates on the SIMCOM modems. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/baconcheese113/1f0264727fce3fa51a5bb06fa031aed2) for a walkthrough